# EF6 Linq Select with Sum and Where

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following statement which is part of a larger select:

```
something.Orders.Sum(o => o.InvoiceItems.Where(i => i.TypeID == Types.SomeType)
                .Sum(i => i.Amount * i.Quantity))
```

This works fine and returns correct sum of amounts for all orders if I remove the Where extension. But with the Where it returns null. Where am I wrong in here? Thanks!

Comment: Does it return null? Or does it return an empty enumerable?

Comment: Are you 100% positive that your where predicate should be returning data (there are InvoiceItems where that predicate is true). For example, does "something.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.InvoiceItems.Where(i => i.TypeID == Types.SomeType))" return any InvoiceItems?

Comment: `Sum` can return `null` if you have nullable values. are they nullable?

Comment: It returns null, I checked.

Comment: Where you went wrong is on the `Where`.. Ha, ha, ha... Sorry. Is your `i.TypeID` an integer and your `Types.SomeType` an enum? Your where clause probably doesn't match any items. When this happens to me (it does a lot), I assign each of the predicates to a `var` variable and check them individually. Try that.

Comment: @Backs Yes, they are nullable

Comment: @ChrisKnight There are plenty of data for that TypeID, I checked that

Comment: @Brandon Yes, my TypeID is int and Types is enum. I think this is exactly where the problem is. Do you have a sample of what you said?

Comment: because its EF and EF sucks try change it to `Where(i => i.TypeID == (int)Types.SomeType)`

Comment: @Pikkolat I don't even know if that's the problem, it was just a guess because it looks like the types mismatch. I'm 50% sure that you can match an `int` to `enum`. If your `Where` is what's failing: then your Id isn't matching what you're looking for.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Pretty sure it has nothing to do with EF. I just checked and it's possible to compare (using a `Where`) an `int` to and `enum` value. We'll need more info to answer the question.

Comment: are you expecing `0` or other value instead of `null`?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No, boxing it in int didn't help.

Comment: @Backs I'm checking for nulls later in the code after the data is received, so I expect either a value or null

Comment: The generated SQL should contain some clues

Comment: @Aducci The whole statement is very complicated, the resulted SQL is almost impossible to read, unfortunately.

Comment: I just found out that if I change the statement and add Where clause to the Orders list like this: something.Orders.Where(o => o.StatusID != Statuses.Canceled).Sum(o => o.InvoiceItems.Sum(i => i.Amount * i.Quantity)) that Where works fine, filtering out unwanted orders. But the InvoiceItems filter still doesn't work as expected. Order.StatusID is integer and Statuses is enum.

Comment: Also, if I change the Where from i => i.TypeID == Types.SomeType to something like i => i.Amount > 10 then this Where predicate works just fine. It's definitely the Types enum